# Remote debugging in haskell

Tags: debugging, haskell, remote-debugging, ghci, leksah

Is it possible to debug haskell remotely? If the code is running on a server can I step through the code remotely using any tools?

I have started using leksah for haskell development, I'm quite new to it but finding it quite useful. However I would like to know if remote debugging is possible using leksah or any other tools, as I play with large datasets that usually becomes hard to import from testing environment to local setup. The ability to step through the code remotely would be greatly useful.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any remote debugging tools via a google search.

The closest I found is a project called hat, which generates a trace file and allows you to debug that trace file offline.

http://projects.haskell.org/hat/

Good luck.

Comment: That's a shame. I didn't like the Debug/Trace approach, I don't think I would use it, I'd rather use a debugger locally - thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a variety of [officially listed Haskell debugging options](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Debugging). There is a [related SO post for debugging in leksah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425184/using-leksah-debugger-with-programs-that-use-readln-and-similar) from a few years ago, and if you decide to use IntelliJ there is also a [Remote Debugger](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/remote-debugger) plugin.