# Leksah 0.15.0.1, GHC 7.10.1 : Is it possible to pass user input to a Haskell program which is launched inside Leksah Haskell IDE? If yes, how?

Tags: haskell, leksah

**Question** :

Is it possible to run a program in Leksah and **enter user input** ? If yes, **how** ?

**Reason for asking:**

I tried **two** different ways to run a program in Leksah and enter user input and both ways **failed**:

**First approach** - running in normal mode (not GHCi) :

Simply writing to console works fine :

[image]

However, Leksah hangs when I try to run the following program, asking for input :

[image]

**Second approach** : using GHCi in Leksah.

Evaluating `main2` works fine.
Evaluating `main` hangs. It is not possible to enter input.

[image]

Any idea how one can enter user input when launching a program in Leksah ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid little has changed since the [last time this came up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425184/using-leksah-debugger-with-programs-that-use-readln-and-similar).  You can now make a GHCJS app and run it in the Out pane.  It can include DOM input elements and handle DOM events.  StdIn input is still unsupported.

Comment: Many thanks ! Is there a workaround ? Perhaps running a GHCi in a terminal ? Or just running the executable from a terminal ? Is there a conflict between running an external GHCi + Leksah on the same project ? Is that problematic in some way or does that (GHCi in terminal + Leksah) work on the same cabal project just fine ?

Comment: @jhegedus Have you actually tried doing that? I imagine firing up a terminal, running ghci and seeing if you get any issues has a quicker turnaround time than asking people on the internet.

Comment: @Cubic I don't know for sure what works and conflicts with Leksah and what not. I could keep playing around with it for hours, or just get a simple answer from an expert. This answer can also help other people facing the same problem. I consider your comment unconstructive and  trolling.

Comment: There are a couple of work arounds described in the answers to the question I linked to.

Comment: Thanks, I try, for now, I just use cabal repl. Seems to work fine, I hope it does not conflict with Leksah in some mysterious way behind the scenes.